# Image resource cannot be found after using sbt debian:packageBin

Tags: image, playframework

I have put my images into the path `app/assets/images` but after I used the command 
`sbt debian:packageBin`
and deployed it to my server, the images couldn't be found.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I use 'activator dist'. It zips everything including the assets.

Comment: U mean this is SBT's bug which could not zips the content in the file of assets?

Answer (score 1):

I have sovled this problem
I did not put these images into the package after I used the command 

`sbt debian:package`

I put these code into the 

`build.sbt`


`import NativePackagerHelper._
...
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= directory("public")`